# Click to display and edit in redactor js wysiwyg html editor

Tags: jquery, html, css, wysiwyg, redactor

I have three different divs with `contenteditable="true"`. And I have set the redactor wysiwyg toolbar to be fixed.

html:

```
<div id="toolbar_wrapper">
  <div id="toolbar">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="redactor redactor1" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>I am a Header</h1>
    <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="redactor redactor2" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>I am a Header</h1>
    <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="redactor redactor3" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>I am a Header</h1>
    <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
```

css:

```
#toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Now I when any on divs (`redactor1` or `redactor2` or `redactor3`) is clicked, display the redactor toolbar for that clicked div. And hide when clicked outside that div. How do I do that? Thank you.

Sample code in [code.io](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/wKvrZJ)

Comment: Something like **[this](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/pjodWx)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes its displaying when clicked, but I want the redactor `#toolbar` to be fixed above the `#content` not above each clicked div. And also its not working, I mean I can't edit the contents with the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your js file

```
$(function()
{
    $('.redactor1').redactor({
        focus: true,
        toolbarExternal: '#toolbar'
    });

});

$(document).click(function(){
    $("#toolbar_wrapper").hide();
});
$("#toolbar_wrapper").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  $("#toolbar_wrapper").css('display','block');
});
$(".redactor").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
    $("#toolbar_wrapper").css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: Sorry but if I click any tool in the toolbar, the toolbar hides.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a toolbar for each instance of redactor:

```
  <div id="toolbar_wrapper">
    <div class='toolbar' id="toolbar_for_1"></div>
    <div class='toolbar' id="toolbar_for_2"></div>
    <div class='toolbar' id="toolbar_for_3"></div>
  </div>
```

and then turn on the corresponding toolbar each time you have focus on a specific redactor:

```
$(function() {
  $.each($('.redactor'), function(i){
    var toolbar_id = '#toolbar_for_' + (i + 1);
    $(this).redactor({
      focus: true,
      toolbarExternal: toolbar_id,
      focusCallback: function(e){
        $(".toolbar").hide();
        $(toolbar_id).show();
      }
    });
  });
})
```

See working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MajKRr)